# Numpy multiply (2, 4) and (4, 4) without broadcasting

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Performing the matrix operation (2, 4) * (4, 4) yields a (2, 4) matrix. Obviously, without broadcasting this would not be a valid matrix multiplication. How would this same result be accomplished without broadcasting?

#### Example with broadcasting

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1 0 0 0], [0 0 1 0]])

b = np.array([[2.25 1.5  0.   0.  ], [1.5  2.   0.   0.  ], [0.   0.   2.25 1.5 ], [0.   0.   1.5  2.  ]])

print(a * b)
```

#### Result

```
[[2.25 1.5  0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   2.25 1.5 ]]
```

Comment: that is `a @ b` and this has nothing to do with broadcasting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform matrix multiplication, which is not what numpy does with the `*` operator. Instead you need to use the function `matmul`:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
  [1, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 1, 0],
])
b = np.array([
  [2.25, 1.5,  0.,   0.  ], 
  [1.5,  2.,   0.,   0.  ], 
  [0.,   0.,   2.25, 1.5 ], 
  [0.,   0.,   1.5,  2.  ],
])

print(np.matmul(a, b))
```